# How do I check if the vote I cast in review audit is actually cast on the original post?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, up-votes

Sometimes in review an audit comes along. Oh nice answer/question, I upvote. Then a message appears

> This was a test, you passed.

But I don't know if my upvote is counting. Do I have go to the answer/question and make it for real?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post from 2017 suggests the vote does **not** get registered on the real post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345933/upvoting-a-first-posts-review-audit-doesnt-actually-upvote-the-post). If you want your vote to stick, you have to go through to the real post and vote.

> I (correctly) upvoted it as a reasonable post and passed the review audit; however, when I looked at it later, my upvote hadn't actually been applied. (I was able to manually upvote it later).

I'm not sure if that's accurate, or still true, but it's the best indicator I have.

Not that it matters, I also don't agree with it. Upvotes should carry.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing you do in a review audit is real. I think of review audits as mock-ups based on real posts. The post score will be shown differently from the real score, the author's picture and reputation may be fake, and the post itself may already have been deleted. We cannot interact with this mirage. Follow the link to the real post to upvote for real.

[Shog9 confirms here that votes on a review audit don't count, and explains why they shouldn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242840/votes-on-review-audit-are-not-placed-on-the-question/242841#242841)

Comment: That's a good point about why upvotes on audits shouldn't be automatically applied, which I hadn't considered. *"[T]he net effect would be to greatly increase the score of a handful of posts that were chosen because they already scored more than the norm."*